# Singleton class not working with component navigation

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to create a singleton class so I could avoid opening the same database again.

I've read about creating a class provider with a static variable so it could stay the same, but I've seen that each time I navigate to another component, the static variable content is lost.

Here's my code so far
`couchbase.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Couchbase } from "nativescript-couchbase";
import * as connection from "tns-core-modules/connectivity";
import { isAndroid } from "platform";

@Injectable()
export class CouchbaseService {
    private static database: any;

    constructor() {
        console.log("enter constructor")
    }

    public static init(){
        if(!CouchbaseService.database) {
            console.log("enter init")
            CouchbaseService.database = new Couchbase("data");
        }
        return CouchbaseService.database;
    }

    public getDatabase() {
        return CouchbaseService.database;
    }
    ...

}
```

`app.component.ts`: I've read that calling `init` from this parent class would make the app keep it for the children (note that I also tried passing the `CouchbaseService` as a constructor parameter, changing the method `init` to non-static)

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import * as Platform from "platform";
import { CouchbaseService } from './services/couchbase.service';

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})

export class AppComponent { 
    constructor() {
        CouchbaseService.init();
    }
}
```

In my `app.module.ts` file, I added `CouchbaseService` to the `providers` list.

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";
import { NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular";
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { NativeScriptUIDataFormModule } from "nativescript-ui-dataform/angular";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { registerElement } from 'nativescript-angular/element-registry';
import { CardView } from 'nativescript-cardview';
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app.routing";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

import { CouchbaseService } from "./services/couchbase.service";


import { HomeComponent } from "./components/home/home.component";
registerElement('CardView', () => CardView);
registerElement("MapboxView", () => require("nativescript-mapbox").MapboxView);
registerElement("Fab", () => require("nativescript-floatingactionbutton").Fab);

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptUIListViewModule,
        NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptUIDataFormModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        NativeScriptHttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        CouchbaseService,
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ],
    entryComponents: [
    ],
})
/*
Pass your application module to the bootstrapModule function located in main.ts to start your app
*/
export class AppModule { }
```

When I look at the logs in the terminal, seems like each time I navigate to another component the service is restarted, so it looses the value of `database`.

I'm using NativeScript 4 with Angular 5 and TypeScript 2.7.2.

Comment: `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` will create the service once at the root of the application.  Everywhere it's injected will receive the same instance.

Comment: @JasonWhite `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` was introduced in Angular 6. The user is using Angular 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how should make use of a singleton service. Let's do this way:

Change your service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Couchbase } from "nativescript-couchbase";
import * as connection from "tns-core-modules/connectivity";
import { isAndroid } from "platform";

@Injectable()
export class CouchbaseService {

    private database: any;

    constructor() {
        console.log("enter constructor")
        this.init();
    }

    private init(){
        if(!this.database) {
            console.log("enter init")
            this.database = new Couchbase("data");
        }
    }

    public getDatabase() {
        return this.database;
    }
    ...

}
```

In your `AppModule` [or module where you have your service] specify the service in `@NgModule`'s provider array like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    YourComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [CouchbaseService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now in your component use constructor dependency injection like this:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import * as Platform from "platform";
import { CouchbaseService } from './services/couchbase.service';

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})

export class AppComponent { 
    constructor(private service: CouchbaseService) {
        console.log(this.service.getDatabase());
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a code like that before checking on the singleton service. The only difference I can see is the usage of `BrowserModule`, is that what I need? cause I'm still losing the value of `database`

Comment: After adding the BrowserModule, I'm getting this: `**ERROR** ReferenceError: Event is not defined JS: bootstrap: ERROR BOOTSTRAPPING ANGULAR JS: bootstrap: Event is not defined JS: JS: ReferenceError: Event is not defined`. I'm editing my question with the modules in case you would need it. The question here is: if this is truly a singleton class, why is terminal always printing `enter init`? that means it is not saving the value (and if I print it, the result is `undefined`)

Comment: I am not sure what could be the issue in your setup. But it works fine in my environment. In fact in stackblitaz project as well. See the demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-tutorial-ptzdxw?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @amlibtest Do not try to copy paste the whole code, I would suggest to understand and apply it on your project. While using NativeScript, you use `NativeScriptModule` instead of `BrowserModule` as your application is not going to run inside a browser. This should have been covered in the getting started guide of NativeScript Angular. The answer is just mark your service as a provider on app module (root), so only one instance will be created and it should be available throughout your app.

Comment: @Manoj yes, I have `NativeScriptModule`, but still, why is `database` printing `undefined` after the first time then? I was wondering if I should do something like in the ng2-translate module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't comment on that without seeing proper code. Either try to create a minimal Playground Sample (remember couchbase plugin does not work with Playground) Or share a Git repo with sample project.

Comment: @Manoj ok, I shared you a link to my project https://github.com/amasrie/tns-medical

Comment: I think you must spend good time in learning the basics of Angular before you use it for your project. You are totally missing all about dependency injection in constructor and creating your own instances which is the problem here. Also remember, you can not use Angular code or pass in instance of a service to a worker thread, that's a limitation.

Comment: @Manoj Ok, I already tried passing the service as a constructor param and that didn't work, maybe is the worker as you say. The idea of using workers is that I didn't want to freeze my app while querying the database, but I'll try that. Thank you

Comment: @Manoj I made a simple test removing the use of the worker form the first components in the navigation, but I still can see the `init` function of the service entering the condition where `database` is `undefined`. Maybe there is something else I need to change? I also added the constructor params. I'm also changing my base class, but seems like that didn't change a thing

Comment: @Manoj After removing all instances of my service (including components and workers), it seems to work as expected. Thank you, you may add the answer to mark it as the right one.